# (angular directive) bind an object to all property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

Say I have an object `{propA: 'valueA', propB: 'valueB'}` on the controller instance `ctrl` as `dirProps` and I want to bind this object to all the attribute on a directive. I can't change the definition of the directive. I have to write

```
<my-dir
  prop-a="ctrl.dirProps.propA"
  prop-b="ctrl.dirProps.propB"
></my-dir>
```

Is there a way to improve this because my object that binds to the directive might be dynamic.

Something like this

```
<my-dir
  all-attr="ctrl.dirProps"
></my-dir>
```

would be nice.

Comment: What I'm asking is something like [JSX Spread Attributes](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html)

Comment: Tried anything so far ??

Comment: @SameerK Looks like I have to create another directive

Comment: I guess existing directive link function can help us here. Can you show the problem via fiddle or plnkr ??

Comment: I think the code sample is clear enough. I want to do something like JSX Spread Attributes

Comment: Thought of fiddle or plnkr as they provide clear picture of the issue, but thats fine and i have no idea about JSX spread attributes. The 2nd code sample can be used, but my concern is that how the object properties set as directive attribute will be utilized inside directive??

Comment: The link of JSX Spread Attributes explains very well. Basically I want to map from `{dirProps: {PropA: 'valueA'}}` to `<my-dir propA="dirProps.propA"></my-dir>`